# Modify markup with a scheme function

Tags: lilypond, lily-scheme

This seems quite straightforward, but I've spent far too much time struggling.

I frequently using markup of the form:

```
\markup \with-url#"https:\\youtu.be .....  t=214" {ref}
```

This creates a hyperlinked text that links directly to a spot in a video on Youtube.  Each instance needs a different value after `t=`.

Ideally, I would like a function that can be invoke with a number or string (that's not a big deal), so that my input would look something like:

`c2^\refer "346"`, or maybe `c2^#(refer 346)`, or some such thing.

I have struggled with including `\markup` in a scheme function, or trying `define-markup-function` all with no success.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick:

```
vid = "videoid"
baseURL = #(format #f "https://youtube.com/watch?v=~a" vid)


#(define-markup-command (refer layout props ts) (number?)
   (interpret-markup layout props
                     (markup #:with-url (format #f "~a&t=~a" baseURL ts) "ref")))

refer =
#(define-music-function (ts) (number?)
   #{
     -\markup\refer #ts
   #})

{ c2\refer 234 }
```

Comment: First --- MANY thanks.  I never ceased to be amazed at the combination of willingness and competence.

A couple of details - I am using the youtube shortened URL, so I replaced the use of (format ...) for the baseURL with the actual shortened one.

And thanks for showing me the use of (format #f....  I guess at some point I should get some actual Scheme documentation.  The closest I've come is writing LISP code, but that was back in the 1960s.
I modified the definition of refer to take minutes and seconds and do the arithmetic to convert it to seconds, for Youtube wants.  THANKS!!

Comment: @KenLedeen You’re welcome :). As far as I know YouTube does also take timestamps like `t=1m34s`, so you might just paste the timestamp together in this format and leave the arithmetic part (although it is not hard) to YouTube.

Comment: and now for a followup question that reveals the limit of my knowledge.

from the example above, which works perfectly, I assumed that I could invoke \refer from inside my own markup commands. For example

\markup \refer 3 14

But this doesn’t work. I get error messages like:

...ince.ly:234:16: error: syntax error, unexpected SYMBOL \markup \refer 1 2 My usage seems entirely consistent with the way it’s used in the defined music function.

what am I not understanding?

Comment: @KenLedeen Resolving arguments to markup function does use much less parsing magic. So for Lilypond to know you are passing a number you actually need to pass a scheme number, e.g. do `\markup\refer #1`.